# Prevent front end users from sending requests from changed webpage

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Suppose I have disable a button on the front end and any user can enable it by Chrome tools. How can I prevent it? Can I validate whether the request front end is changed?

I use Codegniter.

Comment: You don't control the front end. What you can do is only accept valid input in the back end.

Comment: you can do something like this:- `if($_REQUEST['buttton_name']){return false}` or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track by having a state in your controller passed down to the view.

```
function contact()
{
  $disabled= true;

  if($this->input->post('submit') && ! $disabled)
  {
    //do something

  }
  
  $this->load->view('contact', ['disabled' => $disabled]);
}
```

In your view will be

```
  <button name="submit" <?= $disabled? 'disabled="disabled"': '' ?>>Submit</button>
```